# axis equals one syntax error

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to make a a step function plot using values from a txt file to run equations that will generate a plot.

My txt file looks something like

```
      x0     x1        y0        y1
   0.000  0.110 -0.000050 -0.046207
   0.110  0.143 -0.046206 -0.049596
   0.143  1.000 -0.049596  0.000000
```

Eqautions I'd like to use are

```
1. (((y1-yo)/(x1-x0)*(1-x0))+y0)
2. (-u + K/2)/e
```

I get an error on axis=1 saying,

```
df['u'] = df.apply(lambda row: (((row.y1-row.y0)/(row.x1-row.x0)*(1-row.x0))+row.y0, axis=1)
                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Below is my script

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import csv

import pandas as pd

x=[]
y=[]
K=-2.69028905
e=1

df = pd.read_csv('vol_values.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
print(df)
df['u'] = df.apply(lambda row: (((row.y1-row.y0)/(row.x1-row.x0)*(1-row.x0))+row.y0, axis=1)
df['V'] = df.apply(lambda row: -row.u + K/2, axis=1)
df
print(df)
x=df['x in KxC']
y=df['Voltage']

plt.step(x,y)
```

If there's anything fishy on my codes, please let me know.
I would only like to use the code i generated above using apply and lambda row function to generate equations!

Comment: Are you the same person who asked a similar question about the exact same problem earlier and then deleted it after getting an answer? If so, why are you still using `apply` after I showed you how t do this more simply with elementwise series operations?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a matching brace there after "**+row.y0** " . It should be "**+row.y0)**":

```
df['u'] = df.apply(lambda row: (((row.y1-row.y0)/(row.x1-row.x0)*(1-row.x0))+row.y0 ) , axis=1)
```

This must fix that syntax error

Comment: Thank you. I fixed this error but Is there any way I can have the x=df function be like x=df['x0, x1'] so that the x axis is a step function from x0 to x1 as a connected two points with one y value? My diagram will be a step function plot