# how to account for the x values in txt file to plot a step function plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a a step function plot using values from a txt file to run equations that will generate a plot.

The problem is, when i run the script, the plot is not a step function that go from 0 -> 0.110, and 0.110 to 0.143, and 0.143 to 1. It goes from 0 to 
0, 0 to 0.11, 0.11 to 0.143. So, basically, it only plots step function based on x0, not including x1. The step function should look like x0 -> x1, for instance, 0 ->0.110, 0.110 -> 0.143, 0.143 -> 1.

Is there any way I can change the x=df.['x0'] so that it also includes the x1 value with it? I would like to keep my code the way it is without changing the whole script using another method if possible.

My txt file looks something like

```
      x0     x1        y0        y1
   0.000  0.110 -0.000050 -0.046207
   0.110  0.143 -0.046206 -0.049596
   0.143  1.000 -0.049596  0.000000
```

Eqautions I'd like to use are

```
1. (((y1-yo)/(x1-x0)*(1-x0))+y0)
2. (-u + K/2)/e
```

Below is my script

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import csv

import pandas as pd

x=[]
y=[]
K=-2.69028905
e=1

df = pd.read_csv('vol_values.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
print(df)
df['u'] = df.apply(lambda row: (((row.y1-row.y0)/(row.x1-row.x0)*(1-row.x0))+row.y0 ) , axis=1)
df['V'] = df.apply(lambda row: -row.u + K/2, axis=1)
df
print(df)
x=df['x0']
x1=df['x1']
y=df['V']
plt.step(x,y)
```

Comment: What is the difference to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50711725/axis-equals-one-syntax-error), where somebody points out that you have asked this question before and deleted it, after receiving an answer?

Comment: The other question I asked didn't use the method I wanted. I have to use this specific method unfortunately. No offense to the people answering my question and I apologize for the redundant questions. Also, I came up with another question that i couldn't solve on my own, so im asking it here again.The other question was about the syntax error reagrding axis=1 and this one is about using the x0 and x1 values in my txt file for the step function plot diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print(df[['x0', 'x1', 'V']])

x0     x1         V
0  0.000  0.110 -0.925485
1  0.110  0.143 -1.207511
2  0.143  1.000 -1.345145

x = [df.x0.iloc[0]] + df.x1.tolist()
# [0.0, 0.11, 0.143000, 1.0]

y = [df.V.iloc[0]] + df.V.tolist()
# [-0.9254854, -0.9254854, -1.207511, -1.34514]

plt.step(x, y)
```

[image]